# line chart type diagram with bokeh- change the str format

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda, spyder, bokeh

I have date and 3 other elements of each job, that python reed them from a txt. and now I want to use these information to create a diagram with Bokeh.

#### how can I use date format(x-axies.start and end time of each job) and string formats(y-axies.3 elements for each job) in bokeh?

***Does anyone know of a working example for the Step Line chart type which exemplifies how to build the necessary data structure?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: the original answer below is obsolete, as the ggplot compat layer was removed from Bokeh many years ago. However, Bokeh now has its own built-in `Step` glyph:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/plotting.html#step-lines

---

***OBSOLETE ANSWER:***

> I'm not sure if this is what you are asking for or not, but you can
>   use ggplot.py to generate a step-chart and then output to Bokeh:
>
> http://docs.bokeh.org/docs/gallery/step.html
>
> There will probably be a native step chart in Bokeh.charts later this
>   year (or sooner, if an outside contributor pitches in).
>
> You would need to add your own data to this part:
>
> ```
> df = pd.DataFrame({
>     "x": range(100),
>     "y": np.random.choice([-1, 1], 100)
> })
> ```

Comment: Yes exactly I want to have this diagram as result.

Comment: @bigreddot.thanks for your answer. But how can I tell that code about Start and End of each job in x-axies? and also about my y-axies?

Comment: How can I modufy that to use my data? not default or random data?

Comment: :[tag:bigreddot]I have to use matplotlib and create a step graph like this: [link](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/step_demo.html) I have a series of data such start_time and end_time(job run start time as python date) and Node_req (int) for each job that I read them from a file.

Comment: `x1=[start_time+datetime.timedelta(minutes=i) for i in range(60)]
x2 =[end_time+datetime.timedelta(minutes=i) for i in range(60)]
y1 = [node_req for i,_ in enumerate(x1)]

Comment: ## I wonder if I can use drange! to create a cycle for example like that: mpl.dates.drange(run_start_time,end_time,datetime.timedelta(minutes=i) for i in range(60) )`